# using to be "are" after to be "is"

Tags: gerunds, prepositional-phrases, conjugations

can you use To Be verb "are" after another To Be verb "is" like this text,
" technology is are the forefront of the companies ethos"

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. The sentence with _is are_ is certainly not grammatical. I don't know why you would think it would be grammatical.

Comment: I suspect the sentence should be "technology is **at** the forefront of the companies ethos"

Comment: A  combination such as "is are" is not possible in English or any other language I know. I have normal sentences in mind,  not such things as "The applicant/the applicants is/are ...".

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, in this context the phrase is probably "is at." However, in a few specific contexts one can have two conjugations of "to be" in a row:

> 1. I am being (*adjective*) or (*article+noun*) or (*past participle*)

This indicates an ongoing state, usually conceptualized as active. For example, "I am being very irritating, am I not?"

> 2. She is *being*/I am *being*

This is a somewhat awkward or philosophical way of saying "I am (merely) existing." It would only be appropriate in a narrow literary context (e.g. "What are you doing? I am not doing; I am *being*.).

> 3. It depends upon what the meaning of the word "is" is.

In this case, one of the forms of "to be" is being used (note that this very sentence used case 1) as a noun representing the word itself, whereas the other fills its normal role in the sentence. In case you have not seen this before, this is a quote from the 42 president of the United States, Bill Clinton (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3KCEpzAcCg).

Answer (score 0):

You have two main verbs ("is" and "are") juxtaposed in one clause.  This is not allowed.  You may have two such verbs in one clause, but they must be joined by a conjunction to form a compound predicate:

> Technology **is** *and* innovations **are** key to our success.

Or you may place one of the verbs in the independent clause and the other in a following *dependent clause*:

> Technology **is** one of those things *that **are** the at forefront of
>   the company's ethos*.

Answer (score 0):

I've reasons to believe that you heard the above sentence and are trying to make sense out of it.

Here's what you probably heard:

"Technology is at the forefront of the company's ethos."

(Two forms of the same verb cannot occur in the same sentence, as you already know.)